# custom field does not get updated after entering once - FPM_REFRESH not working

Tags: abap, webdynpro

I have enhanced BP data model with custom entity, TYPE 4, updated the mappings and GenIL UI.

When I create a CR to add data on these custom fields, I can enter only once.

If I enter say value '1' on the field and I am still on the same UIBB, I am not able to edit any other value for that field, say I cannot remove the '1' and enter '2' on that field.

Once data is entered and CR is activated, I am able to save the data in database, the only issue comes when I am on a CR trying to add data on that custom UIBB.

Can anyone suggest what could be the missing piece on this? (mappings/feeder class)

In the flush method of UIBB (`IF_FPM_GUIBB_FORM~FLUSH`), I am able to see the old and new values, however in `IF_FPM_GUIBB_FORM~GET_DATA` and `GET_ENTITY_DATA` methods of the feeder class, I am only seeing the old values at `CS_DATA`.

I have redefined the `GET_ENTITY_DATA` and `GET_DATA` methods to assign F4 help from `OVS_HANDLE_2` and setting the field properties respectively.

Comment: Add your code, please. Methods `get_data`, `get_entity_data` and `flush`

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow all the steps from [the guide](https://www.sap.com/documents/2015/07/d6928e5d-5b7c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html). Sometimes you might miss one and the whole things doesn't work.

Did you connect the MDG data model with GENIL by inserting your entity either in `VC_MDG_BS_GENIL_C` or in `VC_MDG_BS_GENIL` view?

If that was not it, then it is probably a mismatch in field name or type. Try debugging from `IF_BS_TYPECASTED_MAP_ASSISTANT~TARGET_FIELD_NAME` or `IF_BS_TYPECASTED_MAP_ASSISTANT~TYPE_ALTERNATIVE` and check if the values are mapped correctly.